# fmt:formatNumber with two spaces

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

mobilenumber is in this format originally: 12345678

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${d.mobilenumber}" pattern="000,00,000" var="pat" /> 
${fn:replace(pat, ",", " ")}
```

Somehow this results in the following format: 12 345 678

Instead of the intended: 123 45 678

Is there a way to use jstl to format a string/number like this?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try it out with `fn:substring()` under ,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

simply as,

```
<c:set value="12345678" var="phone"/>
<c:out value="${fn:substring(phone, 0, 3)} ${fn:substring(phone,3,5)} ${fn:substring(phone,5,8)}"/>
```

It outputs as ,

> 123 45 678

Comment: This is what I had originally,  but the other method would be more optimal if possible

Comment: Thank you :)! Any advice is nice :)

Comment: i suggest you to use the above solution . i am also trying out with `fmtNumber` . will update once i come out with it